# adding custom components to Community page header w/ Jepson theme

Tags: lightning-community, header, custom-theme-layout

**We would like to add a custom lightning component (LWC) to the header of our Community, so that it shows up on all the community pages**.
We have done this in the past w/ the older Customer Account Portal theme.  However, the community we're working with now uses one of the newer themes (Jepson).  More info here: https://advancedcommunities.com/pre-built-themes-in-lightning-communities/

**In these new themes, the header is a "Compact Header" which is configurable in some regards but does not seem to allow adding components**.
i.e. it's not a container as far as I can tell, unlike headers in other themes.

**So what's the best way to do this, short of abandoning this theme?**
Do we need to make a custom theme layout?  (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_theme.htm&type=5)  And if we do, can we use Jepson as a starting point (including retaining the compact header) and just tweak it , or would it have to be completely from scratch?

There seem to be some tricky and/or undocumented aspects to this.  e.g https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005qhIQAQ

Looking for general advice here.

Thanks much!

Comment: I am also trying to add a custom lwc to a community header.  Have you found a solution or a work around?

Comment: @SarahGanci I don't 100% remember, but I think we didn't find any way around this, and are planning on eventually creating a custom theme to replace Jepson

Comment: 2022, same issue again :/